# Copying data from one column to another in the same table sets data to null in original column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a new column `[LastLoginDate-NoTime]` with the data type `Date`. I already have another column `[LastLoginDate]` that is of `Datetime` datatype.

[Columns with the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu6yN.png)

I am trying to copy values from the `LastLoginDate` column to the `LastLoginDate-NoTime` column using this query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[SapUsersExt] 
SET [LastLoginDate] = [LastLoginDate-NoTime]
```

But the problem I am having is that when I execute this query, it sets the data to null in the original column.

Screenshot: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0x7c.png)

I am also trying to convert the data from the `LastLoginDate` to just date format in the new column `LastLoginDate-NoTime` so that I can use it in my application. How would I do that?

Comment: That isn't how an `UPDATE` works, if you use one column to set the value of another, the first column's value is uneffected, *unless* you assign it's value too. Do you, perhaps, have a poorly written `TRIGGER`? Take the time to provide us with a [mre].

Comment: Thank you for your response, I don't think I have a trigger in this table. You say that the first column's value is unaffected but it is affected isn't it? I have added the screenshot for reference.

Comment: I wouldn't make a copy of your data to store it as date. If you want to ignore the time portion just do that when you query it to your application. Not a fan of storing duplicate data. But if you insist on that I would argue to make it a computed column so you never have to update it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I am trying to copy values from the LastLoginDate column to the LastLoginDate-NoTime column using this query*

In that case, you're doing it **exactly backwards** - you should use this SQL instead:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[SapUsersExt] 
SET [LastLoginDate-NoTime] = [LastLoginDate]
```

The first column - right after the `SET` - is the **target column** into which your values will be written.

The second column, after the `=` symbol, is where the data comes from (column or expression).

You had it backwards - setting the column with the actual values, to all `NULL` ....

This of course only works for a "one time" update - this will **not** keep your columns in sync over time, when new data is being inserted. For such a case, you'd need a **computed column**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SapUsersExt
    ADD LastLoginDateOnly AS CAST(LastLoginDate AS DATE) PERSISTED;
```

or a trigger.

Or maybe, you don't even really need to actually **store** that date-only value - just use

```
SELECT
    CAST(LastLoginDate AS DATE), 
    .......
```

if you need to date-only value from `LastLoginDate`

Comment: @Aashu: what **version** of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: Hi @marc_s This is what I got when I ran SELECT @@VERSION: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul 23 2021 13:14:19   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Not sure why the `CAST(...AS DATE)` shouldn't work .... what exactly happened? Did you get an error? No data? Wrong data?